# How can I get ADB to recognize my Spice MI 350?

Tags: adb, spice-mi-350

I want to use my Spice MI 350 for testing an application I'm developing. I have tried following [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html), but so far I cannot get it working.

When I run `adb devices` I get `????????` as device name. The Device Chooser which appears just before running the application also displays `???????`.

How do I get my `adb` to recognize my Spice MI 350 (Android 2.3.3) so I can test my application?

**EDIT**
        I work on Ubuntu 11.10 and Eclipse 3.7.

Comment: What operating system is your computer running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work on the Linux 11.10, I solved the problem by researching on various blogs. I particularly found [this link](http://russenreaktor.wordpress.com/2010/12/25/solved-android-no-adb-on-suse-linux-or-no-permissions/) very helpful.

Actually the vendor ID in "/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules" was wrong. As I couldn't find the Spice in the Android's developer site.

Executing command `lsusb` gave me the correct vendor id....

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c31d Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c05a Logitech, Inc. Optical Mouse M90
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 2006:0c03 (-->2006 is the vendor id for Spice MI 350)
```

Now My /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules file looks like:-

SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="2006", MODE="0666" GROUP="plugdev"

Now after restarting adb services... i.e.

```
su
$ adb kill-server
$ adb start-server
$ adb devices
```

The output is :-

```
List of devices attached 
0123456789ABCDEF    device
```

Now when I launch application from eclipse ide it automatically identifies the device....

Comment: in the future, in your question, specify that you are using Ubuntu 11.10 (or what ever OS you are actually using at the time).

Comment: I will remember that.. @RyanConrad,

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a Windows machine, then it sounds like maybe the drivers you are using are not the correct drivers.

Download the [drivers from here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1472026) (at the bottom) and install those drivers on the system.

To install the drivers:

1. connect your phone to your pc with USB debugging mode enabled.
2. Windows will not be able to install drivers on its own. So, go to 'Device Manager'. Under 'Other Devices', you will have your phone's name, Spice Mi-350n/Fly IQ260.
3. Right click and select 'Update Driver Software...' and select 'Browse my computer for driver software' and browse to the location where you extracted the drivers and click 'Next'.